# Function-like option in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, variables, codeblocks, sql-server-2016, cognos

Disclaimer: I'm hobbled by the fact that I do not have permissions to create functions nor stored procedures. That's not going to change.

I have a large code block that:

1. Populates multiple variables with values from individual select statements.
2. Populates additional variables based on mathematical operations performed on the initial variable set.
3. Ultimately populates a single variable with the result of nested IF-ELSE comparing values of the second variable set.

I need to execute this block as part of a select statement.

```
SELECT Alpha, Beta, @Sigma = (result of block above) 
FROM MyTable
```

If it matters, the select statements inside of the block gather information from tables other than `MyTable`.

Other than a function or procedure, how could I execute this? Just doing `@Sigma = (block)` complains about syntax at the first statement after the parentheses.

This result set will eventually be used in a data set/data module in `Cognos v11`.

```
DECLARE @Goal AS decimal(5,4) = 0.7085
DECLARE @StarScore AS decimal(3,2) = 0.00
DECLARE @Q1Start AS date 
DECLARE @Q2Start AS date 
DECLARE @Q3Start AS date 
DECLARE @Q4Start AS date 
DECLARE @CurrentMonth AS int = MONTH(current_timestamp)
DECLARE @FirstOfCurrentMonth AS date =  CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @Q1TBS as decimal(5,4)
DECLARE @Q1TBC As decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @Q1TBD as decimal(5,0)

DECLARE @Q2TBS as decimal(5,4)
DECLARE @Q2TBC As decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @Q2TBD as decimal(5,0)

DECLARE @Q3TBS as decimal(5,4)
DECLARE @Q3TBC As decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @Q3TBD as decimal(5,0)

DECLARE @Q4TBS as decimal(5,4)
DECLARE @Q4TBC As decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @Q4TBD as decimal(5,0)

DECLARE @Baseline decimal(5,4) 
DECLARE @BaselineC As decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @BaselineD as decimal(5,0)
DECLARE @Score as decimal(3,2) = 0.00
DECLARE @Unit as varchar(20) = '  '
DECLARE @UnitName as varchar(50) = ' '

DECLARE @TempCount As Int = 9999

-- Define current rolling 4 quarters. Q4 is the current quarter, Q3-Q1 progressively 1 quarter back. 
IF @CurrentMonth in (1,4,7,10) 
    -- PRINT @FirstofCurrentMonth
    SET @Q1Start = DATEADD(month,-9,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    SET @Q2Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q1Start)
    SET @Q3Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q2Start)--DATEADD(month,-3,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    SET @Q4Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q3Start) -- DATEADD(month,-1,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
IF @CurrentMonth in (2,5,8,11) 
    -- PRINT 'First of Current Month ' + cast(@FirstofCurrentMonth AS varchar(20))
    SET @Q1Start = DATEADD(month,-10,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    -- PRINT 'Q1 ' + CAST(@Q1Start AS VARCHAR(10))
    SET @Q2Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q1Start) -- DATEADD(month,-7,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    -- PRINT 'Q2 ' + CAST(@Q2Start AS VARCHAR(10))
    SET @Q3Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q2Start) -- -4,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    -- PRINT 'Q3 ' + CAST(@Q3Start AS VARCHAR(10))
    SET @Q4Start = DATEADD(month,3,@Q3Start)
    -- PRINT 'Q4 ' + CAST(@Q4Start AS VARCHAR(10))
IF @CurrentMonth in (3,6,9,12) 
    SET @Q1Start = DATEADD(month,-11,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    SET @Q2Start = DATEADD(month,-8,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    SET @Q3Start = DATEADD(month,-5,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)
    SET @Q4Start = DATEADD(month,-2,@FirstOfCurrentMonth)

-- create temp table to hold results   

CREATE TABLE #Scores (
Unit varchar(20),
UnitName varchar(50),
StarScore decimal(3,2)
)

set rowcount 0

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 NULL UnitKey,UNIT_NBR As Unit, UNIT_NM AS UnitName into #Units FROM TableA
WHERE Unit_NBR IS NOT NULL

set rowcount 1
update #Units set UnitKey = 1

--- START CALCULATIONS

while @TempCount > 0
        begin
            set rowcount 0
            select @Unit = Unit, @UnitName = UnitName from #Units WHERE UnitKey = 1
            SELECT @TempCount = Count(*) FROM #Units
            PRINT 'TempCount ' + cast(@TempCount AS varchar(10))

        -- Baseline defined as 2016 annual score for the unit

        SET @BaselineD = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND d.ISSUE_DATE between  '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31')
        -- -- PRINT '2016 total' + cast(@BaselineD AS varchar(5))

        SET @BaselineC = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r   
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND r.[PROPERTY] in ('A','B') AND d.ISSUE_DATE between '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' )

        IF @BaselineD = 0
            SET @Baseline = 0.00
        ELSE 
            SET @Baseline = @BaselineC/@BaselineD
        -- PRINT 'Baseline is ' + cast(@Baseline AS varchar(10))

        -- Calculate 4 quarterly scores for the unit based on date values calculated earlier


        SET @Q1TBC = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND r.[PROPERTY] in ('A','B') AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q1Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q2Start))

        SET @Q1TBD = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q1Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q2Start))
        -- PRINT 'Q1 n - ' + cast(@Q1TBD AS varchar(10))

        IF @Q1TBD = 0
            SET @Q1TBS = 0.000
        ELSE 
            SELECT @Q1TBS = @Q1TBC/@Q1TBD

        SET @Q2TBC = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND r.[PROPERTY] in ('A','B') AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q2Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q3Start)) 

        SET @Q2TBD = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q2Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q3Start))
        -- PRINT 'Q2 n - ' + cast(@Q2TBD AS varchar(10))
        IF @Q2TBD = 0
            SET @Q2TBS = 0.000
        ELSE 
            SELECT @Q2TBS = @Q2TBC/@Q2TBD

        SET @Q3TBC = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND r.[PROPERTY] in ('A','B') AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q3Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q4Start))

        SET @Q3TBD = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q3Start AND DATEADD(day,-1,@Q4Start))
        -- PRINT 'Q3 n - ' + cast(@Q3TBD AS varchar(10))

        IF @Q3TBD = 0
            SET @Q3TBS = 0.000
        ELSE 
            SELECT @Q3TBS = @Q3TBC/@Q3TBD 

        SET @Q4TBC = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND r.[PROPERTY] in ('A','B') AND (d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q4Start AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

        SET @Q4TBD = (SELECT count(r.[PROPERTY]) FROM TableR r
        JOIN TableD d ON r.ITEM_NBR = d.UNIQUE_ID
        JOIN TableA a on r.ITEM_NBR = a.ITEM_NBR
        WHERE a.UNIT_NBR = @Unit AND r.WIDGET_CD = 'XYZ' AND d.ISSUE_DATE between @Q4Start AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        -- PRINT 'Q4 n - ' + cast(@Q4TBD AS varchar(10))

        IF @Q4TBD = 0
            SET @Q4TBS = 0.000
        ELSE
            SELECT @Q4TBS = @Q4TBC/@Q4TBD

        -- PRINT 'Q1 score - ' + cast(@Q1TBS AS varchar(10))
        -- PRINT 'Q2 score - ' + cast(@Q2TBS AS varchar(10))
        -- PRINT 'Q3 score - ' + cast(@Q3TBS AS varchar(10))
        -- PRINT 'Q4 score - ' + cast(@Q4TBS AS varchar(10))

        -- Calculate StarScore

    -- Q1 star score

        IF @Q1TBS < @Goal -- If Q1 < Goal, next compare to baseline
            BEGIN
                IF @Q1TBS < @Baseline -- if less than baseline no score
                    BEGIN           
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + 0
                    END
                ELSE -- it is higher than baseline, still no score in Q1
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + 0

            END

        ELSE 
            SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25


        -- Q2 Star Score 

        IF @Q2TBS < @Goal -- If Q2 < Goal, next compare to Q1
            BEGIN
                IF @Q2TBS < @Q1TBS -- if less than Q1 no score
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + 0
                ELSE -- it is higher than Q1, add .25
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25
            END
        ELSE 
            SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25

        -- Q3 Star Score  

        IF @Q3TBS < @Goal -- If Q3 < Goal, next compare to Q2
            BEGIN
                IF @Q3TBS < @Q2TBS -- if less than Q2 no score
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + 0
                ELSE -- it is higher than Q2, add .25
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25
            END
        ELSE 
            SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25        

            --Q4 Star Score 

        IF @Q4TBS < @Goal -- If Q4 < Goal, next compare to Q3
            BEGIN
                IF @Q4TBS < @Q3TBS -- if less than Q3 no score
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + 0
                ELSE -- it is higher than Q4, add .25
                    SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25
            END
        ELSE 
            SELECT @StarScore = @StarScore + .25    

    -- PRINT 'Score is ' + cast(@StarScore AS varchar(10))

            INSERT INTO #Scores VALUES(@Unit, @UnitName,@StarScore)
            delete #Units WHERE UnitKey = 1
            set rowcount 1
            update #Units set UnitKey = 1
            SET @StarScore = 0.00
        end

set rowcount 0

select * from #Scores
```

Comment: You need to post all of your code, other wise everything is a guess and you may have an [**XY PRoblem**](http://xyproblem.info/), but from what you have provided you don't have to put that code block there... you can simply focus on #3 and do something like `if <condition> set @var = ....` and then in the final select set @Sigma = @var, or just select @var. You don't have to have the logic nested in the select.

Comment: Can't you take your code block, put a semi-colon after each individual statement (if you haven't already), and paste the whole thing into a single sql command in Cognos?

Comment: A [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) is another good way to divvy up and reuse complicated, multi-step computations in one query without having to materialize the intermediate results first (although you may still want to, for performance reasons). And a bunch of nested `IF-ELSE` can often be simplified by judicious use of `CASE`. The only scenario I can think of where something can *only* be accomplished by stored procedures or functions is when the logic has to be made available to others.

Comment: You can do multi step operations in T-SQL as Tab mentioned. It's just a question of whether Cognos allows it (you may need to enable "native" mode if you have that option). Longer term, it's generally not recommended to build complex logic in the reporting tool. Ideally you would have your own replica or ODS or data warehouse where you can create modular efficient rules like this.

Comment: The ETC proposed by @JeroenMostert looks interested. I cobbled together what I wanted to produce, but I have no doubt I did some of "Fly to Charlotte from Atlanta via New York City" exercise to get there. Code added with object names dummied a bit. 

As for later manipulating in Cognos, that will be undertaken by another team, I needed to supply a query that would give them the result set found in #Scores.